# Instantiation type of std::shared_ptr losing const

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following program:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class SharedPtr : public std::shared_ptr<T>
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> Impl;
    template<typename U> friend class SharedPtr;
    SharedPtr( Impl const& other ) : Impl( other ) {}
public:
    SharedPtr( T* newed_ptr ) : Impl( newed_ptr ) {}
    SharedPtr( SharedPtr const& other ) throw() : Impl( other ) {}
    template <typename U> SharedPtr( SharedPtr<U> const& other ) throw() : Impl( other ) {}

    template <typename U> SharedPtr<U> DynamicCast() const throw()
    {
        return SharedPtr<U>( std::dynamic_pointer_cast<U>( *this ) );
    }
};

template<typename T> class Handle : public SharedPtr<T const>
{
    typedef SharedPtr<T const> Base;
    template <typename U> friend class Handle;
public:
    explicit Handle( T const* pObject = 0 ) : Base( pObject ) {}
    Handle( SharedPtr<T> const& src ) : Base( src ) {}
    template <typename Derived>
    Handle( Handle<Derived> const& other ) : Base( other ) {}
    template <typename Derived>
    Handle<Derived> DynamicCast() const throw() {
        SharedPtr<Derived const> tmp = this->Base::template DynamicCast<Derived const>();
        return Handle<Derived>( tmp );
    }
};

class B { public: virtual ~B() {} };
class D : public B{};

void
testit()
{
    Handle<D> p( new D );
    Handle<B> p1( p );
    Handle<D> p2( p1.DynamicCast<D>() );
}
```

I get the following errors (from g++ 4.7.2):

```
noX.cc: In instantiation of ‘SharedPtr<T>::SharedPtr(const SharedPtr<U>&) [with U = const D; T = D]’:
noX.cc|33 col 37| required from ‘Handle<Derived> Handle<T>::DynamicCast() const [with Derived = D; T = B]’
noX.cc|45 col 37| required from here
noX.cc|13 col 88| error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<D>::shared_ptr(const SharedPtr<const D>&)’
noX.cc|13 col 88| note: candidates are:
```

and a long list of candidates.  Microsoft (MSVC 11) gives
a similar message, so I assume that the error is in my code, and
not a compiler error.

Obviously, I don't expect to be able to convert
a `SharedPtr<D const>` to a `SharedPtr<D>` (or
a `std::shared_ptr<D const>` to a `std::shared_ptr<D>`, which is
what Microsoft complains about).  But where does the
`SharedPtr<D>` come from in the first place?  I can't see any
thing in the above code which should create any smart pointer of
any type to a non-const.

Comment: @LucDanton Yes.  That was the error.  I just wasn't looking in the right place.

Comment: A different question for you? What are you trying to accomplish with these classes? Just curious...

Comment: @Dilip Provide a safe functional style interface.  They are partially historically conditioned, but in the actual code, they are, of course, considerably more complex.  In particular, it is `template <typename T, bool condition>` class SharedPtr`, with partial specializations, so that the actual implementation of `SharedPtr` depends on whether the pointed to class supports invasive reference counting or not (and long term, to get rid of non-invasive reference counting, as too dangerous).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance it looks like a `SharedPtr<Derived>` object is being implicitly created for the `Handle( SharedPtr<T> const& src )` call at `return Handle<Derived>( tmp );`

Comment: Well spotted.  I changed the `SharedPtr` constructor to `Handle( SharedPtr<Derived const> const& src )`, and the example code now compiles.  (I'll have to see if that corrects the problem in the real code, but `SharedPtr<Derived>` is clearly an error.

Answer (score 4):

This constructor:

```
Handle( SharedPtr<T> const& src ) : Base( src ) {}
```

relies on the implicit conversion from `SharedPtr<T>` to `SharedPtr<T const>` (i.e. `Base`). But here:

```
return Handle<Derived>( tmp );
```

You want a `SharedPtr<T const>` -> `Handle<T>` conversion, although the only likely candidate is the constructor taking `SharedPtr<T>`. One solution is to change that to:

```
Handle(Base const& src ) : Base( src ) {}
```

'moving' the implicit conversion to callers, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T> class Handle : public SharedPtr<T const>
{
    Handle( SharedPtr<T> const& src ) : Base( src ) {}

    Handle<Derived> DynamicCast() const throw() {
        SharedPtr<Derived const> tmp = this->Base::template DynamicCast<Derived const>();
        return Handle<Derived>( tmp );
    }
```

Your return a `Handle` where T is of type `Derived` without const. T in `SharedPtr<T>` is of type `Derived const` though.